# How to create a multi-page build profile in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lazy-loading, bundling-and-minification

I'm working on a responsive single page app which has grown quite a lot. The app was minified into a single file, which worked quite well until the file size hasn't exceeded 1 MB. It takes quite a few seconds to download it for someone who has low internet bandwidth.

Initially the build config looked like this:

```
var buildConfig = {
    appDir: "build",
    optimize: "uglify2",
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    dir: "dist",
    removeCombined: true,
    inlineText: true,
    modules: [{
        name: "app",
        include: ["dep1", "dep2"]
    }]
};
```

It has changed later, with `findNestedDependencies` set to `false`, so other modules could be specified independently.

```
var buildConfig = {
    appDir: "build",
    optimize: "uglify2",
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    findNestedDependencies: false,
    dir: "dist",
    removeCombined: true,
    inlineText: true,
    modules: [{
        name: "app",
        include: ["dep1", "dep2"]
    }, {
        name: "subapps/home/home.controller",
        include: ["dep3"],
        exclude: ["app"]
    }, {
        name: "subapps/about/about.controller",
        include: ["dep4"],
        exclude: ["app"]
    }] // the real configuration would have 40+ modules here
};
```

It works, however this configuration is problematic due to the number of async `require` calls, which are no longer found automatically.

Manual configuration seems error prone (some modules are removed, new are being added), my first thought was to find the dependencies on my own with a simple script with esprima, I didn't find any r.js method which would allow me to do it.

Have you encountered a similar problem before? How did you solve it? I have a feeling that I might be missing something obvious here.

Comment: I have a little project, [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy) that is probably very close to what you want. It is a RequireJS plugin (e.g. declare a dependency as `'lazy!dep1'`) and it lets your code lazy load that dependency when needed. The good thing is that it is integrated with r.js, so that the build creates the necessary bundles of split code automatically.